# OAuthSwift - pop-up safari view, not jump to Safari

Tags: swift, oauth-2.0, alamofire

I'm using OAuthSwift and Alamofire to make an OAuth2 request, all works, but I want to make the UX a bit better: When the user taps on the log in the OAuthSwift jumps to Safari where collects credentials and authenticate the user, then jumps back to the app. I want to present that screen inside the app like a popup view controller over the login screen.

```
let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(consumerKey:        Credentials.client_id,
                                 consumerSecret:     Credentials.client_secret,
                                 authorizeUrl:       ZohoURL.authTokenUrl,
                                 responseType:       "code")
    
    let _ = oauthswift.authorize(withCallbackURL: ZohoURL.redirect_uri, scope: "", state: "") { (result) in
        
        switch result {
        case .success(_):
            print("success")
        case .failure(_):
            print("error")
            }
        }
    }
```

The code works for authentication (not included the handling the response, not relevant for this question)

I read something about `authorizeURLHandler` for `oauthswift` but I didn't manage to understand how to use it.

I'm open to another implementation or cocoa pod if that will make it possible.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended option for an iOS app is to use an ASWebAuthenticationSession popup window, which feels integrated.

The AppAuth libraries do this automatically so I would aim to borrow some ideas from them.

If it helps, see these resources of mine, and maybe start by running my code sample on a simulator. Hopefully it will give you something useful to compare against.

- [iOS Code Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.ios)
- [Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2020/02/22/ios-code-sample-overview/)